# Why is casting so expensive in Swift compared to just... leaving it as AnyObject?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I'm getting a value back from `NSUserDefaults`, a value I'm sure is an array of `String`s. There are tens of thousands of strings in the array. I do the following:

```
let identifiers = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("UserIdentifiers") as! [String]
```

Take **0.5** seconds to process on an iPhone 6.

Remove the cast at the end? **0.000107 seconds**.

Is it checking every single item in the array to ensure that it is a string? Can it... not do that?

Even if I just cast it as [AnyObject] it still takes around 0.3 seconds.

Comment: Have your tried to cast it `as! NSArray`, and how long it cost

Comment: @Leo That sped it up a **lot**. Maybe it's just not a fan of Swift. :/

Comment: I think because `objectForKey` is return a `Anyobject?` ,and the  `[String] ` is swift type Array,Swift will have to loop every part to ensure that it can be converted successfully.

Comment: Just a note to "There are tens of thousands of strings in the array". You shouldn't then store it in `NSUserDefaults`. It is meant to store small amounts of data like user settings, not to be a database for "tens of thousands" of items. `NSUserDefaults` are stored in Plist. Imagine the price of parsing and storing this in memory on a device

Answer (score 0):

Lukas Kukacka is correct... The flaw starts the instant u start using NSUserDefaults for storing huge number of values. You use NSUserDefaults for small amounts of data that u need to access globally.
You should rather make a service class of sorts to do this rather than built in UserDefaults.

Regarding the type casting, String is swift based and NSString is much faster that String. U might lose some functionality but it'll be much faster. Have a look at the following link to get a preface:

http://en.swifter.tips/string-nsstring/